# How do you check for null or undefined on a variable assigned to a missing anonymous function expression?

Tags: javascript, undefined, nullreferenceexception, anonymous-function, function-expression

When commenting out the anonymous function expression "a" below, how do you properly check for NULL on "b"? Use case: Lets say "a" is an in-page JS include (library) that is assigned to "b", but the library failed to load and now we have a console error.

```
var a = function () { return 'Success!'; } // Exclude this line
var b = a();
if (typeof b !== 'undefined' || b !== null) { // These checks do not work.
   console.log(b);
} else {
   console.log('Failed!');
}
```

Comment: If you remove `a` function you'll get referenceError on `a`

Comment: Yeah, what @YouneL said - the check *works*, the problem is that the code fails before getting there.

Comment: Have you tried: `var b = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a() : undefined` or more specifically: `var b = typeof a == 'function' ? a() : undefined` Then you can just check: `if (typeof b !== 'undefined') {/*...*/}`

Comment: @Mark_M or `try...catch` which is designed for situations like that. Then again, if `a` wasn't loaded, I don't think error handling is really the way to go but finding the root reason and removing it.

Comment: @vlaz yes, I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your use case correctly, this line of code is in your side of 
the app:

```
var b = a();
```

If that is correct, you can re-assign `a` conditionally with itself or with a new function or an object.
This is a common pattern when you want to check if a global variable exists.

Here is a running example when `a` is not exists:

```js
// library 
//var a = function () { return 'Success!'; } // Exclude this line

// my app
var a = a || function(){};
var b = a();
if (b) {
   console.log(b);
} else {
   console.log('Failed!');
}
```

And here is the same code when `a` exists:

```js
// library 
var a = function () { return 'Success!'; } // Exclude this line

// my app
var a = a || function(){};
var b = a();
if (b) {
   console.log(b);
} else {
   console.log('Failed!');
}
```